# itk_post_read(): setgid(): Operation not permitted

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm getting a lot of this error in my apache log

**itk_post_read(): setgid(): Operation not permitted**

What should I do?

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [apache2-mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) and for some reason it doesn't have enough rights to switch to a different system group using setgid(). Make sure Apache is running as root. I can't be any more specific if I don't have more information about your system.

(Yes, using apache2-mpm-itk means Apache must run as root. [Read this ("Quirks and warnings") before screaming](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).)